# Is the Markov property under $\mathbb{P} $ preserved under change to a measure $\mathbb{Q} $ absolutely continuous to $\mathbb{P} $ .

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation, martingales, markov-process

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F}, \{\mathcal{F}_n \}, \mathbb{P})$, be a filtered probability space, $\mathcal{F}= \sigma\{F_n,n\in \mathbb{N}\} $, $M_n$ a nonnegative martingale, and $\mathbb{E} \mathrm{M}_n=1$ for all $n$. Define $$\mathbb{Q}_n(A)=\int_A M_n \mathrm{d} \,\mathbb{P},\quad A\in 
\mathcal{F}_n $$
Then, $\mathbb{Q}_n$ determines a probability measure $\mathbb{Q}$. If $X_n$ is Markov process under $\mathbb{P}$, is it still a Markov process under $\mathbb{Q}$?